# What TypeScript type should NextJS _app.tsx Component and pageProps be?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Here's the default _app.tsx from NextJS:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  )
}
```

The problem is, as soon as you switch to TypeScript, you get a warning under ES6Lint that these types are intrinsicly set to type 'any'. That being said, I can't figure out what type to set these two to that wont cause more errors later of mismatched types. What TypeScript types should I cast these two as?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The built-in `AppProps` type is now **generic**. To use your custom `PageProps` just pass it into the `AppProps` type:

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';

interface CustomPageProps { // <--- your custom page props
   // your props
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps<CustomPageProps>) {
                                             //   ^^^ use your custom props here
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
                    // ^^^^^ pageProps is now typeof CustomPageProps
}
```

Comment: This is the recommended way, however this makes `pageProps` a type of any, which isn't very useful. Is there any way to apply a generic when using one of the date fetching methods, such as `getInitialProps`?

Comment: @rantao, see my answer below. I explain how to make the `AppProps` generic extend to `pageProps` as well, which gives you the option to provide a structure for the initial props.

Comment: @rantao Updated my answer - new built-in types from `nextjs` are now generic.

Answer (score 47):

### Latest solution: NextJS `AppProps`

As of next.js version [12.3.0](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v12.3.0), the generic passed to `AppProps` will get passed to `pageProps` ([see relevant PR](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/38867)). See example below:

```js
// importing the provided NextJS type
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

// use the type and pass it your page props type
export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<CustomPageProps>) {
  //...
}
```

---

### Old solution (pre next.js 12.3.0):

#### Improved `AppProps` to allow customisable `pageProps`

NextJS provides an `AppProps` type out of the box that you can import and use in your `_app` component. This will provide the types you asked for. However, this type restricts `pageProps` to the *`any`* type by default, which may not be what you want.

If you want more control over this, `AppProps` takes a type argument, but only passes it down to `Component`, leaving `pageProps` as the *`any`* type no matter what.

We can fix this with a tweak to the `AppProps` type that actually passes it's type argument to `pageProps` as well. See working example below.

#### `_app.tsx`

```js
// importing the provided NextJS type
import type { AppProps as NextAppProps } from "next/app";

// modified version - allows for custom pageProps type, falling back to 'any'
type AppProps<P = any> = {
  pageProps: P;
} & Omit<NextAppProps<P>, "pageProps">;

// use the new type like so, replacing 'CustomPageProps' with whatever you want
export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<CustomPageProps>) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you still getting the warning of 'Missing return type on function', just add return type JSX.Element

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): JSX.Element {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#custom-app

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need the `err` object too:

```js
export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps,
  err,
}: AppProps & { err: any }) {
  // Workaround for https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8592
  return <Component {...pageProps} err={err} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need types that will be caught up by `getInitialProps` as well.
There they are:

```
type Props<P> = AppProps & P;

interface AppType<P> {
  (props: Props<P>): ReactElement;
  getInitialProps?: (context: AppContext) => Props<P> | Promise<Props<P>>;
}
```