# _app.tsx to have getInitialProps and other custom props too, need proper Typscript type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

My _app.tsx files what to be something on these lines

```
interface CmsAppProps extends AppProps {
  pageData: boolean
}

const CmsApp: NextPage<CmsAppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps, pageData }) => {
  // ...some component details
}

CmsApp.getInitialProps = async (context: NextPageContext) => {
   // some data process here
   return {
     pageData: true
   }
}
```

Problem here is, typescript is throwing error as: `Type '(_ctx: NextPageContext) => Promise<{ pageData: true; }>' is not assignable to type '(context: NextPageContext) => CmsAppProps | Promise<CmsAppProps>'`

Looks like it expense me to return data same as what is argument of component props. I cannot return `Component` and `pageProps` from getInitialProps.

If I replace type `NextPage` with  React.FC then it obviously doesn't contain `getInitialProps` props. Plus doesn't has relation like what is being sent from getInitialProps also will be passed on to the component.

Is there a correct way to put everything right in typescript?

Comment: what is AmcAppProps?

Comment: Props you return from the `_app`'s `getInitialProps` will be available under `pageProps`, meaning `pageData` should be accessible from `pageProps.pageData`, and not destructured from the top context object. You can't type the `_app` page the same way you do other pages, it has specific typings.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67464299/15351640