# Trying to use React.Component in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here's _app.tsx from a bare bones react auth example

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react",
import * as React from "react"
export default function App({
  React.Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
```

}

It wont compile because it says Component is an 'any' type
I thought the solution was to import Component from React but it doesnt seem to have worked.

Comment: Check out my answer related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722812/what-typescript-type-should-nextjs-app-tsx-component-and-pageprops-be/64722865#64722865

Comment: thanks, in your code posted there the compiler throws an error saying, "session.user.name" session.user is possibly undefined and refuses to compile further

Answer (score 1):

You should import `Session` type from `next/auth` and use it with `CustomProps` generic type.

```
import { Session } from "next-auth";
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import * as React from "react";

interface CustomPageProps {
  session: Session; // <------------ use it here
}

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<CustomPageProps>) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that app.tsx file now is ok but on index.tsx  session is undefined. Should I just start a the project again using javascript? Cos it seems im out of my depth. I tried importing Session, it uses UseSession() and calls it, but still won't compile because it says it equals null.

Comment: It might be that its an error thrown by ESLint, is it being too strict?

Comment: @Keith It sounds like a different issue, not really related with this one. If the typescript error is gone - the main problem is fixed. Maybe you could create a new question with the new problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the type of your custom props like below.

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import * as React from "react";

interface CustomPageProps {
  session: YOUR_SESSION_TYPE_HERE;
}

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<CustomPageProps>) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what to put instead of YOUR_SESSION_TYPE_HERE though